# Can I call a variable from my .NET codebehind page in the actual aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say in my codebehind .cs file, I set a variable:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = 2;
}
```

I want to display this dynamically in my aspx page. But this code won't work:

```
<% Response.Write(x); %>
```

How can i accomplish this? Is there any way to pass variables?

Answer (score 11):

Your variable only exists in the `Page_Load` method.

Declare it at the class level, set it in the `Page_Load`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but for future reference:

x in your example is a local variable. Meaning that it can only be accessed from within the scope of the method (in this case Page_Load event). To make this variable available in your aspx page you could make it a property.

**Code behind:**

```
Protected int YourNumber {get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int YourNumber = 2;
}
```

**ASPX Code:**

```
<%= Response.Write(YourNumber); %>
```